# SubSonic 3.0.0.3 Update Exception

Tags: exception, subsonic3

When I attempt to update in SubSonic I'm greeted with a Null Reference Exception.

This is the exception message I get:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","StackTrace":"   at SubSonic.Query.Update.GetCommand()

I've checked the object I'm updating and there are no missing fields, all the class properties match the database column names.

Any Ideas what this could be?
Cheers Tony

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently this is an [issue](http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/issues#issue/57) already found. I've followed what the OP of the issue stated and it works fine.

This is how to fix it for the time being:

Go to : http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/tree/master , then click on download and select 3.0.0.3.

In Subsonic.Core/Query/Update.cs go to the "GetCommand" method (line 244)

Change `x => x.Name.Equals`

for this
`x => x.QualifiedName.Equals`

Compile it and your sorted.

Comment: This still isn't fixed in 3.0.0.4, guess it's time to switch to Hibernate.

Comment: @BrianV I switched a long time ago, use a mixture of NHibernate and Insight.Database. Works very nicely