# C# SubSonic SQLite: NullReferenceException on Update

Tags: c#, sqlite, subsonic3

I have seen some older posts similar to this, but I seem to be getting this using SQLite rather than SQL Server.

I think the version is 3.0.0.3.

I am doing an update on an object, in this particular case, the object is passed into a form and saved there...Save() method to repository is on the same class. I have checked the properties before the update and all seems ok? The object is retrieved, a single property updated then the attempt to save.

Error Message:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

   at SubSonic.Query.Update.GetCommand()

   at SubSonic.Query.Update.Execute()

   at SubSonic.Repository.SimpleRepository.Update[T](T item)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is a known bug in 3.0.0.3:

See these links:

[SubSonic 3.0.0.3 Update Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178021/subsonic-3-0-0-3-update-exception)
http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2009/11/playing-with-sqlite-subsonic3-and-repository-mode/

Unfortunately I just figured out what "Git" is and now need to see how I can get the source, change it, compile it and use that until a new update is released.

**Update:**

Downloaded the changes from the updated source indicated in the second link above (integratedwebsystems) This fixed the problem.

As it turns out, downloads from Github are basic zip downloads with all the source and VS projects etc, easily done.